# How to check encoding of a csv file on a Mac?

Tags: macos, csv, encoding

I'm having trouble to process a few files because of it's encoding. I can't find out whats the right encoding so I can make Python/Pandas process it accordingly. I'm riding a Mac and I can't find out how to discover the encoding of the csv file. Can someone help?

Comment: Try `file -I yourFile` in Terminal.

Answer (score 1):

There is a python package called **chardet** (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet) that does exactly what you want do.